# The ADT just can't work

Tags: android, batch-file, eclipse-plugin, adt

After studying [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407479/sdk-manager-does-not-find-java) and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023179/android-sdk-and-avd-manager-will-not-run), running the SDK manager from the ADT still prompts an error from the console log:

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\java.exe -jar lib\archquery.jar is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` 

`Invalid path`

`The system cannot find the file specified.`

I promise I can find the `java.exe`  file, and `lib\archquery.jar` does exist, but the batch file just show the same error again.

I have changed the find_java.bat file to

```
set javaw_exe=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\javaw.exe
```

to directly locate the `java.exe` and `javaw.exe` files.

I don't know what happened at all?
Can someone offer me the correct batch file? (I download it on 2013/8/1, I can't find older one)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to set up the Environment variables using [How do I set or change the PATH system variable?](http://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml).

For now, open command prompt. Change directory to the bin directory(@ C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.x_xx\bin) and issue this command:

```
java -jar ..\lib\archquery.jar
```

The `lib` directory is one level up and `..` will get you the parent directory.

Comment: But the script is written in `android.bat`, it calls the `java_exe` and the `jar` file is the target. Where should I edit it?

Comment: Yes, I have set my system PATH variable to `~\jdk~\bin` directory.

Comment: @Stallman Not sure what's wrong here. You are welcome to take a look at `android.bat` that I have: [Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8am1mh4ax0dmmad/android.bat).

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\java.exe -jar lib\archquery.jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
Same warning result even using your bat file.

Comment: @Stallman As a last resort, check if java bin directory is located at `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\` or `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\`, and that both Path variable(user and system) are set. Else, follow `Ray Trask's` advice.

Answer (score 1):

modify android.bat

1. comment out line 36 that tries to detect where java.exe is located and hardcode location :

set java_exe=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\java.exe
rem call lib\find_java.bat

1. Comment out line 43 that tries to detect current architecture (x86 or x86_64) and hardcode accordingly :

rem for /f "delims=" %%a in ('"%java_exe%" -jar lib\archquery.jar') do 
set swt_path=lib\x86_64