# Android sdk manager won't open and I don't have a java folder

Tags: android

I just re-installed Windows. Now after I installed java and eclipse, the sdk manger won't open.

I searched StackOverflow and found the following solution"

> Make sure your java\bin directory is in your path statement before the
> windows\system32 directory. The SDK Manager uses java and it was
> finding the one in the system32 folder.

This won't work for me because I do not have a java folder. I'm assuming it should be on the `c` drive where the windows folder is?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your eclipse/windows/java is installed for right version. For instance, if your windows is 64bit, you have to use eclipse for 64bit and JDK for 64bit as well.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have an environment variable JAVA_HOME pointing to the Java SDK location. Notice that you must install JDK not JRE.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure you install Java SDK right, you try open your Eclipse IDE. If that is OK, it proves that Java SDK is installed correctly. Then make sure your Android SDK can find Java SDK path your installed.

Comment: hI, I can open my eclipse id k.  I did unstall and reinstall java and the java folder is now there, but when I try to open the android sdk manager still does not come up and in the console I get a error saying "'C:\ec' is not recognized as an internal or external command,"

Comment: @Tedpottel Make sure your can use Java commands in command line, click the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407479/sdk-manager-does-not-find-java) to find more details.